# Scale an SVG to it's viewBox or smaller

Tags: css, svg

I have an inline `<SVG>` that defines it's `viewBox` but not it's `height` or `width`. I used to set `width/height` to the same values as the `viewBox` while creating the SVG; the benefit is that the final image is scaled to the SVG's natural units, which I want; the problem is that a fixed `width/height` might overflow the parent container in the final page. Removing `width/height` from the `<SVG>` causes the image to be rendered as large as the parent container allows, which is almost always larger than the SVG's natural units.

Is there a way to scale an `<SVG>` to it's natural units, yet scale it down (!) if the parent container is too small?

Comment: max-height/max-width ?

Answer (score 0):

If you're not bound to using the inline svg (and not bound to IE scaling...), an svg in `<img>` is your friend.

> When an SVG file has a `viewBox`, and it is embedded within an `<img>`,
>   browsers will (nearly always) scale the image to match the aspect
>   ratio defined in the `viewBox`.

HTML

```
<figure>
  <figcaption><code>img</code>, auto size</figcaption>
  <div>
    <img src="https://s3-us-west-2.amazonaws.com/s.cdpn.io/91525/potofgold.svg">
  </div>
</figure>
```

[Result](https://codepen.io/AmeliaBR/pen/MYbzaW)

Inline SVG scaling support is not as far... [Read from this amazing article to learn more about how this works](https://css-tricks.com/scale-svg/#article-header-id-6) See point 4 for a wide-support solution. It recommends using a `padding-bottom` hack, which is common in iframe-embeds also.